# AngularJS Dynamic email validation element, When I fill out the email check element, It's reset

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation

I would like to create a form with several fields: name, last name, ... and add one or several email. The user should enter the first mandatory email address. After he should have the possibility to click on "Add email" for adding a new email address. He could add 4 others emails.

The system should be verify if the format is correct and register the data in a DB.

Could you tell me which is the best practice for doing that?

Kind Regards,

Comment: Have a look at [material chips](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/chips) component. You can valid each input by using regex and [events](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdChips) from the directive.

Answer (score 0):

In the Database:
You should have separate table for storing email address's with foreign key that will be pointing to the main table

Table structure will look like this 
ID,Email,Foreign-Key ID

In the Service layer  you should have model class that will take email as array parameter

email class

```
class Email {
public int id,
public string email
}
```

in the main class

```
class Main  {
email:Email[]
}
```

in the front end 
you should clone the input type whenever the add email button is clicked and push the new element to an array and send it to the service layer